# Echo text by many variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 vars, which are forwarded by php (index.php?a=v1&&b=v6&&c=v10)

Now I want to echo a text (from mysql) by these specific vars.

mysql-table:

index.php?a=v1&&b=v6&&c=v10

```
    id | 1
    variable1 | "v1"
    variable2 | "v6"
    variable3 | "v10"
    text | "this is the text for v1&v6&v10"
```

index.php?a=v3&&b=v8&&c=v12

```
    id | 2
    variable1 | "v3"
    variable2 | "v8"
    variable3 | "v12"
    text | "this is the text for v3&v8&v12"
```

what is the mysql-query?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM text_table WHERE ???;";
```

Comment: What is in your mysql table? What do the values represent? Could you edit your post to be a bit more specific?

Comment: why are you using 2 `&` index.php?a=v1&&b=v6&&c=v10 to my knowledge there is no tutorial that would suggest using 2, umm did you look for a tutorial first...

Comment: Do you mean you want to build a query from GET variables? In that case, this duplicates more than several other questions. However, I can't quite figure out precisely what you're trying to ask .. if you can improve this question, please flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="index.php?a=v1&b=v6&c=v10">Link 1</a>

<?php 

if(isset($_GET)){
    foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value=stripslashes($value);
        }
        $_GET[$key]=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}

$query = mysql_query('SELECT *
                        FROM my_table 
                        WHERE a LIKE '.$_GET['a'].' 
                        AND b LIKE '.$_GET['b'].' 
                        AND c LIKE '.$_GET['c']);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $a = $row['a'];
        $b = $row['b'];
        $c = $row['c'];
        echo "This is the text for {$a}&{$b}&{$c}";
    }
}else{
    echo 'No results';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     a,
     b,
     c,
     'This is the text for ' + a + '&' + b + '&' + c
FROM mysql-table
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, any idea why so I can better help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE a = '.$_GET['a'].' AND b = '.$_GET['b'].' AND c = '.$_GET['c']);
$affectedRows = mysql_affected_rows();
for($i = 0; $i < $affectedRows; $i++){
    $currentResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $a = $currentResult['a'];
    $b = $currentResult['b'];
    $c = $currentResult['c'];
    echo "this is the text for {$a}&{$b}&{$c}";
}
```

If that is what you are asking for. If you need to insert those values, use this query:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table SET a = "'.$_GET['a'].'", b = "'.$_GET['b'].'", c = "'.$_GET['c'].'" ');
```

Which, however, is quite insecure. I'd recommend, before inserting these values, do following:

```
$sqlA = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a']);
$sqlB = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['b']);
$sqlC = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['c']);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table SET a = "'.$sqlA.'", b = "'.$sqlB.'", c = "'.$sqlC.'" ');
```

Comment: You don't need to call mysql_affected_rows, just use                       while($currentresult=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

Comment: Oh, interesting. Didn't know that, thanks :)